# What is the meaning of the Greek words “born of women” as they relate to John the Baptist and to Jesus Christ?

Tags: greek, word-study, matthew, jesus, luke

In Matthew 11:11 Jesus says:

> Among them that are born of women there hath not risen a greater than John the Baptist [KJV]

I understand that the relevant Greek words here (and in Luke 7:28) are ‘gennetos’ (born) and ‘gyne’ (woman). (Source: William D. Mounce ‘Interlinear for the Rest of Us’)

There can be no doubt that Jesus was ‘greater’ than John.  Yet was not Jesus ‘born’ of women as John the Baptist was ‘born’ of women?  Does Jesus exclude himself from the statement, “born of women”?  Is Jesus comparing himself with John the Baptist?  Surely Jesus does not regard himself as lesser than John!

Please note, however, that my question is NOT asking if or how John the Baptist could be greater than Jesus.

My question is asking about the meaning of the Greek word ‘gennetos’ in Matthew 11:11 and in Luke 7:28 as it applies to Jesus.

I welcome any insights into the Greek words that shed light on the differences between the birth of John the Baptist and the birth of Jesus.  Please note, however, that I am not a Greek scholar.  The Interlinear I use could well be entitled ‘Idiot’s Guide to N.T. Greek’ (with apologies to W.D. Mounce).

Comment: The previous question [... why does Jesus say ...](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26713/in-luke-728-why-does-jesus-say-no-one-among-those-born-of-women-is-greater-than) did not deal with the word 'born' and the answers concentrated on comparisons between the greatness/lessness of Jesus and John.

Comment: Well spotted. I found three other similar (but not related) questions on B.H.  None of them seek to understand the meaning of the Greek words to do with "born".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ‘Born’ and ‘Come’ of women

‘Born’ of women in Matthew 11:11, regarding the entering into the world of John the Baptist, his parents Zacharias and Elizabeth, is the translation of the word *gennetois* (see also Luke 7:28) which Liddell & Scott [American Edition 1854] say is derived from *gennaw* (the ‘w’ is omega, a long ‘o’). [Bible hub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/11-11.htm) says that *gennetois* is an adjective and is the dative, plural masculine.

Liddell & Scott gives the meaning ‘to beget’ for the verb *gennaw* and ‘begotten’ for the adjective *gennetois*. Thayer [2nd Edition 1958] agrees completely with Liddell & Scott in this regard.

Of Jesus, Paul says that he is *genomenon* of woman, Galatians 4:4. Bagster’s Analytical Lexicon says this is the accusative, singular, masculine and neuter, participle, aorist 2 of the verb *ginomai*, to come or to become.

Jesus, here in Galatians 4:4, is ‘come’ of woman but not, here, ‘begotten’ of woman.

- ‘Begotten’ - naturally - of woman

Jesus says, recorded in John 16:21, that ‘a woman … in travail … hath sorrow … but as soon as she is delivered (*tikto*) of the child she remembereth no more the anguish for joy that a man is begotten (*gennaw*) into the world’. Note : delivery first, results in a begetting.

Luke records the birth of John the Baptist in Luke 1:57 ‘Now Elisabeth’s full time came that she should be delivered (*tikto*) and she brought forth (*gennao*) a son.

In both the above cases the delivery of the child and the cutting of the cord result in a new, independent entity being in the world. This is called a begetting. Delivery first, results in a begetting.

- The Only Begotten Son of God

When the concept of begetting is mentioned of Jesus, it is in connection with his Father in heaven.

> For God so loved the world that he gave his only begotten Son (*monogenes*) [John 3:16 KJV]

Both Luke (2:7) and Matthew (1:25) record that ‘Mary … brought forth (*tikto*) the son of her, the *prototokos*. Neither evangelist states that this is a ‘begetting’.

*Prototokos* does not mean, intrinsically, ‘firstborn’. The root *tokos* means ‘usury’ see Matthew 25:27 and Luke 19:23, and the translation of *prototokos* should reflect that root meaning.

Of Jesus’ conception it is heralded by the angel Gabriel that

> … thou shalt conceive in thy womb … and bring forth (*tikto*) a son …  [Luke 1:31 KJV]
>
> … the conception … the begetting (*gennao*) holy shall be called Son of God … [Luke 1:35 KJV]

This second reference, Luke 1:35, describes the result of :

1. … the Holy Spirit shall come upon thee
2. … the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee

The result of these two divine influences and activities - is that a begetting is present in the womb of the virgin. And this begetting is prior to a delivery taking place.

A new individual entity is already present in the world, prior to the delivery of a child.

Likewise, in Matthew’s record (1:20), the angel informs Joseph in a dream that ‘that which in her is begotten (*gennaw*) of Spirit is holy’. Again, there is a new individual entity in the world, already. But she is not yet *tikto*, delivered.

This is not a natural birth. It is supernatural.

Luke records (2:1) that ‘Jesus having been begotten (*gennaw*) in Bethlehem …’. Now we know that Mary was already great with child, Luke 2:4 and 5, when Joseph and she journeyed from Nazareth to Bethlehem. Her conception occurred in Galilee.

There was a begetting within her, by virtue of her conception. This *results* in a begetting in Bethlehem. *But it is still not attributed to Mary*.

---

It is not said that Jesus is ‘begotten of Mary’, only that ‘having been begotten’ in Bethlehem. The wording is most careful. There is a definite avoidance, in all of these scriptures, of stating that Jesus was ‘begotten’ of Mary. It is just not there.

Nowhere is Jesus said to be ‘begotten’ of Mary.

He is ‘come’ of woman, Galatians 4:4.

He, himself, is the only begotten Son - of God.

Comment: "Nowhere is Jesus said to be ‘begotten’ of Mary." ???  What of Matt 1:16, 20, 2:1, Luke 1:35??  Same verb as in (say) Matt 1:1-15 for humans.

Comment: I've covered all of these in detail. The text never says 'begotten of Mary'. The language is very precise.

Comment: I think you are making a (very fine) distinction that the Scriptures do not.

Comment: Further, monogenes (as per BDAG and others) means "only type" or unique.  It comes from a different root: monogennetos means only begotten but not monogenes.

Comment: @Dottard Charles Lee Irons and others have strongly contested what you are saying about _monogenes_. I would suggest you consider his online treatment of the word.

Comment: I have considered much of this but take a different view (obviously) in line with modern linguistic analysis.

Comment: @Dottard I prefer to stay with Athanasius, myself. He was a Greek speaker.

Comment: … as are many who disagree.

Comment: The system is discouraging me from further comment. But I am willing to be invited to a chat room for further discussion.

Comment: Jesus specifically said, Very truly I tell you, whoever believes in me will do the works I have been doing … "  This does not make us greater that Jesus.

Comment: Galatians 4:4 is interesting. The Authorised Version clearly says "God sent forth his Son, made of a woman, made under the law."  Luke chapter 2 is also useful in describing the sequence of events.

Comment: In Gal 4:4, AV, the same Greek word, ginomai, is translated "made" in "made of a woman" and also "made under the law".  The point appears to be that "made" means something distinctly different than another word that might have been used, "born".  Adam was not born under (the sentence of death for having broken) the law, but when he sinned he came under that sentence, or curse.  And that curse was passed on to all Adam's descendants.  Jesus, having been made, not born, of a woman, was not born under that sentence, but instead was "made to be" under that curse so he could redeem the rest of man.

Answer (score 1):

This is less complicated than it first appears.  The phrase "born of a woman" or, "born of women" is a common Hebrew idiom for humanity generally.  It is used:

- Of John the Baptist, Matt 11:11, Luke 7:28
- Of Jesus, Gal 4:4
- Of humans generally, Job 14:1, 15:14, 25:4.

I note the following comments by well known commentaries:

**Benson:**

> Among them that are born of women — That is, among the whole race of
>   mankind in all former ages,

**Barnes:**

> Among them that are born of women - This is an emphatic way of saying
>   that there "had never" been a greater "man" than John. See Job 14:1.

**Meyer's**

> among those born of woman. Intended to denote the category of men
>   according to that nature which is peculiar to the whole race in virtue
>   of its origin (mortality, weakness, sinfulness, and so on).

Bengel's Gnomen

> *them that are born of women* An expression of universal extent.

The fact that Jesus is described similarly (Gal 4:4) is to demonstrate His humanity without diminishing His divinity.  See below.

Now to the subtle differences between Gal 4:4 (about Jesus) and Matt 11:11/Luke 7:28 (about John the Baptist).

**Matt 11:11 -**

γεννητοῖς (gennētois = born from the root noun γεννητός gennetos derived from the root verb γεννάω gennao) is an Adjective Dative Masculine Plural; γυναικῶν (gynaikōn = of women) is a Noun Genitive Feminine Plural.  It is only used in Matt 11:11 and Luke 7:28.

**Gal 4:4 -**

γενόμενον (genomenon = born or became from the root verb γεννάω gennao) is a Verb Aorist Participle Middle, Accusative Masculine Singular; γυναικός (gynaikos = of a woman) is a Noun Genitive Feminine Singular

The verb is used of the process of procreation most famously in Matt 1:1-20 of the progenitors of Messiah.  It is also used of Christ Himself (via Mary and/or the Holy Spirit) in places like Matt 1:16, 20, 2:1, Luke 1:35, etc.

Thus, we find that the same words are used to describe Jesus' human origins as the rest of us to confirm His unity with humanity, again, without diminishing His divinity.

Comment: . . .  then I think you are left with a conundrum. If Jesus of Nazareth is (as you say) 'begotten of woman' is he then inferior to John the Baptist ?

Comment: Absolutely not!  He is just as human as John the Baptist as both were born of women.  However, Jesus was also Jehovah God Almighty.  I do not understand your assertion at all.

Comment: Then who is the greatest begotten of women ?

Comment: I think you need to stop applying Greek logic to a Hebrew text.  Jesus clearly said John was the greatest Human and the greatest prophet.  Jesus was also a prophet - so does that make Jesus an inferior prophet to John?  Jesus was also human or do you suggest he was not human?

Comment: It isn't a hebrew text. It is written in the Greek language. Jesus Christ is the only begotten Son of God. He possesses every attribute of Divine nature and he possesses every attribute of human nature. I ask again : Who was the greatest begotten of women ?

Comment: It is Hebrew thought expressed in Greek language.  Jesus pronounced John the Baptist the greatest born of women.  But that does not make Jesus inferior because He was also the son of man.  You will chase your tail forever on this one.

Comment: The system is discouraging further comment. Which is probably just as well. I notice that in the chat room you are identified under another user name.

Comment: To be "born of a woman", as I understand it, applies to the processes of a woman giving birth to a child. It is a purely a physical, human function. Been there, done that. But Jesus was not begotten of a woman. The begetting happens before the giving birth part. The physical birth of both John and Jesus was natural, inasmuch as they were both "born of a woman." However, the begetting was quite different.  Appreciate your contribution and your insights, but I suspect there is more to it than at first meets the eye!

Comment: @Lesley - That is all very well except that the Bible specifically talks about Jesus as the Holy one which is begotten in Mary, Luke 1:35.  See also Matt 1:16, 20 (KJV).

Comment: That the begetting is by the power of the Holy Spirit is not questioned.

Comment: The phrase does in fact describe Jesus' human origins, but his origin was still different than the rest of mankind, indicated by the use of the word "made" rather than "born" in Gal 4:4.  Whether made or born, the origin is still from the womb, but the similarity ends there.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps he was elevating women by drawing attention to the fact that its only by female, does mankind come into this world.  The 'church' is also referred to as being spiritually female.

Comment: Please note that personal opinions do not make for a well thought-out and researched answer.  Biblical evidence is required to support claims.  Please take our tour to find out how we are different to other sites: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Please supply some Biblical evidence with this answer

Comment: This opinion might have some validity, but the word "elevating" might not be the best choice.